# Ruby install jcode

Tags: ruby, utf-8

I'm trying to get 'jcode' for ruby, but I type "gem install jcode" and it says nothing exists?

Does anyone know why? I'm trying to manipulate UTF-8 encoded strings.

Answer (score 7):

Ruby >= 1.9 doesn't require jcode, a module to handle japanese (EUC/SJIS) strings, as it supports unicode natively.

This should fix the problem:

```
require 'jcode' if RUBY_VERSION < '1.9'
```

but must say I did not test it deeply...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried simply:

```
require 'jcode'
```

?

As it happens, jcode is part of the Ruby Standard Library.

Answer (score 0):

Try not to include it at all. It should be included automatically in later versions of Ruby.