# Is it acceptable to push a clone of a Google Code project to Github?

Tags: github, google-code

I'm trying to use the `gdata` gem in a Rails project. The [main development branch](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-ruby-util/) of the gem doesn't support Ruby 1.9 (it `require`s `'jcode'`, which [isn't needed and doesn't exist for Ruby 1.9.x](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3984016/306084)). There are [forks which do](http://code.google.com/r/pablof-gdata/), of course; it's a simple fix. However, to use the gem in a Rails project, I need a version which Bundler can find when I deploy, which means forks of a project using `hg` won't work (unless Bundler has Mercurial support to match its Git support now?).

The "obvious" solution to me is to clone the main Mercurial repository, make the fixes I need, and push this new branch to Github where my deploys can clone it. However, this seems somehow undiplomatic, because a side effect would be the establishment of an unofficial public Github repo of the gem. Is this kind of thing OK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's absolutely fine, as long as the license allows it. Don't forget to link back to the original repos, and clearly state what you are doing in the readme.